# How do I convert a path with a drive letter to a UNC path

Tags: .net, path, unc

How do I convert a path with a drive letter like `W:\Path\Share` to the equivalent unc path like `\\server\Share\File` in .Net?

At the command prompt you can run `net use` and that will list the mappings. How do I get at that info in .Net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use P/Invoke and call on a native function such as [WNetGetUniversalName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/WNetGetUniversalName.html).

Comment: The WNetGetUniversalName function takes a drive-based path for a network resource and returns an information structure that contains a more universal form of the name.

This only works for paths that you have already shared.  It doesn't seem to work for local paths. ie if you are sharing d:\shared as \\mymachine\shared and you call WNetGetUniversalName it fails.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of the shared folders on the current machine in .NET you have to options:

- [Querying the Win32_share WMI class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a45da6f3-aa74-46e2-8e7b-a54562cd2b5e/) using the classes in the System.Management namespace
- Invoking the [NetShareEnum](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetShareEnum.html) function in Win32 using P/Invoke

Note that the calling process will have run in the context of a user with administrative privileges for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about `net use` here is a good solution
[Get UNC Path for Mapped Drive VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765015/get-unc-path-for-mapped-drive-vb-net)

I like the `net use` way.