# Detect that the path is SkyDrive path/Resolve skydrive path to WebDav path

Tags: winapi, webdav, onedrive, windows-networking

Preamble:

If you try to save a file from any Microsoft Office app to SkyDrive folder, then the app (Word etc) will detect that and *switch to accessing SkyDrive directly* via MS extensions for WebDAV (the save icon will turn to Sync icon, you'll see other users accessing the file, etc)

Now, I know how to [Resolve Windows drive letter to a path (subst and network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299814/resolve-windows-drive-letter-to-a-path-subst-and-network), and would like to know whether I can do something similar for SkyDrive paths?

I.e. **how to resolve** `C:\Users\MyUsers\SkyDrive\File.doc` **to** `https://d.docs.live.net/UserId/File.doc`

The [SkyDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx) says nothing about this, and I would like to avoid messing with the SkyDrive client directly.

Thanks!